# Highcharts - Column width not responsive

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts for one of my projects and have unknown problem with columns responsivity. Since it looks like Highcharts column graphs are responsive by default, my is stucked always on the same column width:

```
new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-994d8ebb-5c08-4c83-b4d4-265ed2340006", {
                        "chart": {
                            "type": "column",
                            "alignTicks": false
                        },
                        "plotOptions": {
                            "series": {
                                "dataLabels": {
                                    "enabled": true
                                },
                                "enableMouseTracking": true,
                                "animation": true
                            }
                        },
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Istorija Snage"
                        },
                        "subtitle": {
                            "text": "Poslednjih 30 dana"
                        },
                        "exporting": {
                            "enabled": false
                        },
                        "yAxis": [{
                            "title": {
                                "text": "Snaga"
                            },
                            "labels": {
                                "format": "{value} MW"
                            }
                        }],
                        "xAxis": [{
                            "labels": {
                                "format": "{value:%d-%m-%Y}"
                            },
                            "type": "datetime",
                            "title": {
                                "text": "Datum"
                            }
                        }],
                        "series": [{
                                "type": 'column',
                            "data": [
                                [1505088000000, 0],
                                [1505001600000, 0],
                                [1504915200000, 0],
                                [1504828800000, 0],
                                [1504742400000, 0],
                                [1504656000000, 0],
                                [1504569600000, 149],
                                [1504483200000, 302],
                                [1504396800000, 301],
                                [1504310400000, 301],
                                [1504224000000, 301],
                                [1504137600000, 299],
                                [1504051200000, 283],
                                [1503964800000, 67],
                                [1503878400000, 0],
                                [1503792000000, 0],
                                [1503705600000, 0],
                                [1503619200000, 31],
                                [1503532800000, 100],
                                [1503446400000, 100],
                                [1503273600000, 101],
                                [1503014400000, 94],
                                [1502928000000, 101],
                                [1502841600000, 114],
                                [1502668800000, 187],
                                [1502409600000, 80],
                                [1502236800000, 56],
                                [1502150400000, 46],
                                [1502064000000, 46],
                                [1501977600000, 45]
                            ],
                            "name": "Prosječna snaga (MW)",
                            "_colorIndex": 0,
                            "_symbolIndex": 0,
                            "type": "column",
                            "color": null,
                            "negativeColor": "",
                            "marker": {
                                "enabled": false
                            }
                        }],
                        "credits": {
                            "enabled": false
                        },
                        "legend": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "layout": "horizontal"
                        }
                    });
```

My solution on jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k715f003/).

Example of responsive column width on jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tdpa72q5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that with a `column` chart, and a `datetime` axis, you need to specify a `pointRange`.

Since your data appears to be daily data, you can add a point range of one day (adjust as required):

```
pointRange: 86400000
```

This will make each column take up one day's worth of space on the x axis.

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/k715f003/5/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange

Comment: Hello i think my question is related with this but i cant make mine works, maybe you can help me, url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568858/set-column-width-depending-on-max-datalabel-value