# Set column width depending on max datalabel value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```js
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'heatmap',
      marginTop: 40,
      marginBottom: 80,
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      events: {
        load: function() {
            this.yAxis.forEach(function(xAxis) {
            xAxis.update({
                tickLength: xAxis.maxLabelLength + xAxis.minPixelPadding
            }, false);
          });
          this.redraw();
        }
      }
    },




    xAxis: {
      categories: ['']
    },

    yAxis: [{
      categories: ['', '', '']
    }],

    

    series: [{
      borderWidth: 1,
      dataLabels : {
                          enabled: true,
                          format: '{point.value}'  
                        }   ,
      data: [
        {x: 0, y:0, value: "c"},
        {x: 0, y:1, value: "b"},
        {x: 0, y:2, value: "this wont fit conlumn width aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        +"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        },
      ]     
      
    }]

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I'm using the high chart and I need that the column width fits with the maximum length of the max data labels.

In my example you can see the problem clearly:

[http://jsfiddle.net/aferpq9m/1/]

Comment: Hi @hesolar, You will have to adapt the chart width. Do you always have only one column in your chart?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek in this example i put only 1 column , but i have more less 10 columns and the graphic size is fixed , so i need something to make it responsive

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the result you wanted to achieve, but please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vako51mc/

Comment: @ppotaczek very helpfull, yes the answer is more less that, but i have another problem maybe it cant be done, suppose my div has a fixed width if i made all columns value by the max datalabel content it will probably overflow the div, so i need to make only one column with its maximum datalabel: http://jsfiddle.net/n6h92pe8/2/

Comment: So, would you like to have columns with different widths? Why don't you just split the text into several lines?

Comment: (So, would you like to have columns with different width) yes i need exactly that. (Why don't you just split the text into several lines) In the example i posted in this question , table content text that probably can be in different lines, but in my proyect im using tables with many more data and columns so i need to represent them in a table Tell me if its  posible to do what i need. Many thanks @ppotaczek

Comment: You can achieve that by using breaks. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2hrc1xdf/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks You probably will need to calculate the breaks by some script.

Comment: @ppotaczek thats exactly what i need , answer the question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use breaks. For example:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [''],
  breaks: [{
    from: 0.5,
    to: 0.9,
    breakSize: 0
  }, {
    from: 1,
    to: 1.5,
    breakSize: 0
  }, {
    from: 1.5,
    to: 2,
    breakSize: 0
  }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2hrc1xdf/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks